# Rails accept method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want user could accept offer from another user, I was following the @Andy H answer from [Product orders between 2 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893615/product-orders-between-2-users), but I have this error with link to accept method:

```
No route matches {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"offers", :id=>nil, :job_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :job_id]
#my link to accept method
=link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(@offer), method: :post
```

Here is my offer controller:
     class OffersController < ApplicationController

```
def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @offer = @job.offers.create(offer_params)
    @offer.user_id = current_user.id

    if @offer.save
        redirect_to @job
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end

def accept
    offer = current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
    offer.accept
end

def reject
    offer = current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
    offer.reject
end

private

def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:pirce_offer, :status, :job_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

and my associations:

```
#user
has_many :jobs_given, class_name: 'Job'
has_many :offers_recived, class_name: 'Offer', through: :jobs_given, source: :offers

has_many :offers_made, class_name: 'Offer'
has_many :jobs_take, class_name: 'Job', through: :offers_made, source: :job

#job
belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
has_many :offers
has_many :buyers, class_name: 'User', through: :offers

#offer
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
has_one :seller, class_name: 'User', through: :job
```

and my routes:

```
  resources :jobs do
   resources :offers do
     member do
       post :accept
       post :reject
     end
   end
end
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thank for help!

@edit

My views:

```
  #offers/form
  = simple_form_for([@job, @job.offers.build]) do |f|
    = f.input :pirce_offer
    = f.button :submit

 #offers/offer
 %p= offer.pirce_offer

 =link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(@offer), method: :post 

 #jobs/show
 = render @job.offers

 = render 'offers/form'
```

Comment: Where the `@offer` defined which is being used in the link?

Comment: Try changing it to  `=link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(offer, offer.job_id), method: :post `

Comment: The route should accept both offer and job: `accept_job_offer_path(@job, @offer)` (because offer is nested with job)

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"offers", :id=>nil,
>   :job_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :job_id]

As the error says, the `route` is ***missing required keys*** `:id` and `:job_id`. You are not passing the value for `:job_id` and you are passing `@offer` for `:id` which should be `offer`.

The below should work

```
=link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(offer, offer.job_id), method: :post
```

**or**

```
=link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(offer, @job), method: :post #if you defined @job in the controller
```