# Rails method is working wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my app, where User could accept or reject offer from other users, but something went wrong because, when I create for example 5 offers to job and I try to reject or accept for example third offer, that changes status of the first offer and I don't know what is going on? I follow this topic [Product orders between 2 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893615/product-orders-between-2-users), so maybe I understood something wrong? please help me

my models:

```
#user
has_many :jobs_given, class_name: 'Job'
has_many :offers_recived, class_name: 'Offer', through: :jobs_given, source: :offers

has_many :offers_made, class_name: 'Offer'
has_many :jobs_take, class_name: 'Job', through: :offers_made, source: :job

#job
belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
has_many :offers
has_many :buyers, class_name: 'User', through: :offers

#offer
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
has_one :seller, class_name: 'User', through: :job

def accept
    self.status = true
    save
end

def reject
    self.status = false
    save
end
```

my controller:

```
def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @offer = @job.offers.create(offer_params)
    @offer.user_id = current_user.id

    if @offer.save
        redirect_to @job
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end

def accept
    offer = current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
    offer.accept
    flash[:success] = "Offer accepted!"
    redirect_to :back
end

def reject
    offer = current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "Offer rejected!"
    offer.reject
    redirect_to :back
end

private

def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:pirce_offer, :status, :job_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

my view:

```
 #offers/form
= simple_form_for([@job, @job.offers.build]) do |f|
= f.input :pirce_offer
= f.button :submit

#offers/offer
%p= offer.pirce_offer

= link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(offer, @job), method: :post
= link_to "Reject this offer", reject_job_offer_path(offer, @job), method: :post

#jobs/show
= render @job.offers

= render 'offers/form'
```

@EDIT

```
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"YB0i2/JmroyZBAOOyCom5NDwjxrPsGRFV6Uucnp1dNKmIGgED3H4cB7f2fnutRKCh2OjyQICQghM4Zoy13zZrw==", "job_id"=>"5", "id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Offer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "offers".* FROM "offers" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "offers"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = ? AND "offers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "offers" SET "status" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "offers"."id" = ?  [["status", "f"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-06 08:12:40.425741"], ["id", 1]]
```

Comment: Well, seems that you have some debugging to do. What `params` arrive to your `accept` method? What generates them? And so on.

Comment: I added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> changes status of the first offer

Always remember that in computing, it's *your* fault if something doesn't work correctly.

Systems are extremely versatile and flexible to the degree that unless you have systemic issues, there's no reason why it wouldn't work.

---

**ID**

The issue is almost certainly to do with the `id` you're passing:

```
"job_id"=>"5", "id"=>"1"
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but this is created by this `link_to`:

```
= link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(offer, @job), method: :post
```

Your `accept_job_offer_path` would - IMO - have the params as `[:job_id]` and `[:(offer)id]` respectively. You're sending them the other way around.

Try this:

```
= link_to "Accept this offer", accept_job_offer_path(@job, offer), method: :post
= link_to "Reject this offer", reject_job_offer_path(@job, offer), method: :post
```

This is assuming that your data structure is correct.

---

**Data**

There are some other issues I can see:

```
current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
```

You're calling `current_user.offers_received` without indicating the *job* which received the offer. Surely you'd want to include the job in the process?

Further, you could DRY up your action quite a bit:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jobs do
   match :offer, action: :update, via: [:post, :delete] #-> url.com/jobs/:job_id/offer
end

#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
   def offer
      @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
      offer = current_user.offers_recived.find(params[:id])
offer.accept
      if request.post?
         offer.accept
      elseif request.delete?
         offer.reject
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've nested resources with `:offers` nested under `:jobs` you've got the path the wrong way wrong in your `"Accept this offer"` and `"Reject this offer"` links.

This means that you're sending the id of the offer as `params[:job_id]` (except it won't have an id yet because you only just built it) and then `params[:id]` is the id of `@job`. This is why it is updating the wrong offer - it's because it is updating the offer with the id matching `@job`.

How you're going to find an offer by id when you've only just built it in the form is probably the next step along the road.